# What are the 30 chapters in Proverbs 22:20?

Tags: proverbs, authorship

### [Proverbs 22:20](https://www.catholic.org/bible/book.php?id=24&bible_chapter=22)

> Have I not written for you **thirty chapters** of advice and knowledge...

- What are these 30 chapters?
- Who wrote these to whom?
- Have these chapters ever found?

Comment: There does appear to be a translation problem with this text. KJV makes no numerical reference. YLT says 'written three times' and GLT says 'written the third time'. I am hoping an Hebrew scholar might post an answer.Up-voted for drawing attention to the problem +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some doubt about what exactly was written in Prov 22:20 whether it was "three former things" (or something like that), or "excellent things" or "thirty sayings".  Most modern versions appear to support the latter option such as the NIV, NLT, ESV, BSB, CSB, GNT, etc.  Most of these versions then subdivide the text with subheadings to delineate the 30 sayings of the wise.  Here is how the NIV lists the 30 sayings of the wise.

1. 22:17-21
2. 22:22, 23
3. 22:24, 25
4. 22:26, 27
5. 22:28
6. 22:29
7. 23:1-3
8. 23:4, 5
9. 23:6-8
10. 23:10, 11
11. 23:10, 11
12. 23:12
13. 23:13, 14
14. 23:15, 16
15. 23:17, 18
16. 23:19-21
17. 23:22-25
18. 23:26-28
19. 23:29-35
20. 24:1, 2
21. 24:3, 4
22. 24:5, 6
23. 24:7
24. 24:8, 9
25. 24:10-12
26. 24:13, 14
27. 24:15, 16
28. 24:17, 18
29. 24:19, 20
30. 24:21, 22

Answer (score 0):

My Brother in Yeshua, sent me this as we were discussing the verse. ISV=20. Have I not written for you 30 sayings containing counsel and knowledge,
FCAB [Bauscher]=20. And look, I have written these things to you three times
HNB [MY TRANSLATION]=20. Have not I written to thee excellent things three times,
Three to me has always been repetition of His teaching.

Comment: Hi Dean, welcome to the site. Could you elaborate on how this answers the original question? Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!